# Can $\mathbb{Z}$ be endowed with operations that give it the structure of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Does there exist some definition of addition and multiplication for which the set of all integers is a field?

Comment: "the integers" is just a set of things, and as a set the only thing that matters about it is its cardinality. Its elements don't have any properties until we define external objects (functions, relations, e.g. gcd, divisibility). If there is another countably infinite set for which it is possible to define "addition" and "multiplication" to satisfy the field axioms, then how do you tell this field apart from the integers? By the names of the elements of the set. $\mathbb Q$ is a countably infinite field with the natural definitions of addition and multiplication and thus so can be $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but not a very natural one.

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are both countable, there exists a bijection $\Phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. With the operations
$$m \oplus n := \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(m) + \Phi(n)), \qquad m \otimes n := \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(m)\Phi(n)),$$
$(\mathbb{Z}, \oplus, \otimes)$ is a field, but NB that $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ won't have much to do with the usual addition and multiplication operations on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I have a follow up.Can any set be endowed with the structures of a field.Using a similar method finite fields with prime cardinality have such structures.When we consider modular additions and multiplication.What about other sets.

Comment: No. If a field is finite, then its cardinality is a perfect power of a prime. So, for example, there is no field with exactly $6, 10, 12, 15, \ldots$ elements; for that matter nor is there one with with $0$ or $1$ element (but see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element ).

Comment: (Rather, $6, 10, 12, 14, 15, \ldots$.)

Answer (score 6):

There is a countably infinite field of characteristic $2$ whose elements can be identified with the non-negative integers in a natural way.

Addition can be defined by $2^n+2^m=2^n+2^m$ if $m\neq n$ and  $= 0$ if $m=n$ and extended by the commutative and associative laws. This is "nim addition"

Multiplication can be defined by $2^{2^m}\cdot 2^{2^n}=2^{2^m+2^n}$ if $m\neq n$ and $3\cdot 2^{2^n-1}$ if $m=n$ again extended by associativity and by the distributive law.

There are other ways of defining the field operations. See [Nimbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber).

Clearly any countable field can by definition be put into a bijection with the integers. I thought you might be interested in this rather different construction, even though it doesn't quite do everything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the answer isn't really satisfying. The set of integers is countably infinite. It's therefore in bijection with $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of rational numbers. By transporting the field operations (addition and multiplication) through the bijection, you get a field structure on the set of integers.

Comment: Why not just use $\mathbb Q$? :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I honestly don't know... This would probably confuse the OP less, in fact.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think OP wants to put a suitable structure on $\mathbb Z$ without enlarging it. But your point is well taken.

Comment: @MPW Well the point is that you don't enlarge anything, since both are countable.

Comment: @MPW I think Thomas means taking $\mathbb{Q}$ as the (probably more familiar) countable set whose operations we pull back to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: No, I'm not enlarging it, I'm just using a more natural countable field. $\mathbb F_2(x)$ is a fairly advanced notion - this question could occur before knowing about fields of fractions of polynomials over the field of two elements. @MPW

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: If you mean to use the structure inherited from $\mathbb Q$, you're embedding it there (= enlarging it). Did I misunderstand? Or just use a bijection to carry the operation sfrom $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @MPW There is a bijection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is the point. It's not the usual inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, of course.

Comment: Yes, I understand your answer completely. I didn't understand Thomas's comment. I don't mean to belabor this though. He seems to have suggested what your answer actually is.

Comment: @MPW In my answer I initially put $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}$. For some reason this was the first countable field that popped in my mind. Thomas Andrews (justifiably) suggested that $\mathbb{Q}$ was a better choice (at least it's less likely to confuse the OP).

Comment: Ah ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$